# SQL Commit Method

Tags: sql-server-2008

Should I call trans.Commit() methode after executing DML query? I tried INSERT query and it done and saved in the database successfully without Commit(), So what is the benifit of the Commit() function? and when should I use it?

Comment: How did you verify that the data was committed in database? Did you read the insert data after insert in same transaction?

Comment: right-click on the desired table in the server explorer and choose "show Table Data"

Comment: What was the TransactionScope for trans created?

Comment: what do mean by TransactionScope?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx

Comment: You can refer the example given there. It says scope.Complete() needs to be called to perform commit.

Answer (score 0):

Commit is there so that if you start your SQL with a "BEGIN TRANSACTION", it'll only commit it to the database after you've executed a "COMMIT".  But really, just read the documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190295.aspx

Answer (score 0):

using(trans = connection.BeginTrans())

{

//... do some things

trans.Commit();

}

Answer (score 0):

> Should I call trans.Commit() methode after executing DML query?

Yes, assuming trans is transaction created with transactionscope like serializable.

> I tried INSERT query and it done and saved in the database
>   successfully without Commit(), So what is the benifit of the Commit()
>   function?

Are you sure?

> and when should I use it?

When you want to have atomicity in data updated or read. More here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

You can refer this example
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx

```
// The Complete method commits the transaction. If an exception has been thrown,
// Complete is not  called and the transaction is rolled back.
scope.Complete();
```